# Convert Unix Epoch to dateTime opensearch

Tags: opensearch

I have a json log data with a field contain an Unxi Epoch in second and I want to convert it to humand readable pattern like dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss.

I try to use data prepper of OpenSearch but i didnt found the Unix Epoch pattern to use it.

My json:

```
{"ua": "Mozilla/5.0%20(X11;%20Linux%20x86_64)%20AppleWebKit/537.36%20(KHTML,%20like%20Gecko)%20SamsungBrowser/21.0%20Chrome/110.0.5481.154%20Safari/537.36", "customField": "1685959346", "key3": "test", "securityRule": "test|112122|super"}
```

How can achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ingest pipeline](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/api-reference/ingest-apis/create-update-ingest/) for it. During ingestion, elasticsearch/opensearch will convert and enrich the data.

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/epoch_conversion_pipeline
{
  "description": "Convert Unix Epoch to human-readable format",
  "processors": [
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "org_customField",
        "value": "{{customField}}"
      }
    },
    {
      "script": {
        "source": """
          ctx.customField = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new Date(Long.parseLong(ctx.org_customField) * 1000));
        """
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

```
PUT test_epoch_to_human
{
  "settings": {
    "default_pipeline": "epoch_conversion_pipeline"
  }
}
```

---

```
POST test_epoch_to_human/_doc/1
{
  "ua": "Mozilla/5.0%20(X11;%20Linux%20x86_64)%20AppleWebKit/537.36%20(KHTML,%20like%20Gecko)%20SamsungBrowser/21.0%20Chrome/110.0.5481.154%20Safari/537.36",
  "customField": "1685959346",
  "key3": "test",
  "securityRule": "test|112122|super"
}
```

---

```
GET test_epoch_to_human/_search
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @musab-dogan,
Thanks for your response, when i try to use your json to make the ingest pipeline i have a json_parse_exception.
Have you an idea of why ?

Comment: Hi @YounessCHETOUI, I test it again and the example I shared working fine for me. Maybe there are some special characters for your examples in JSON.

Comment: Yes i found the mistake and it worked ! Thanks you

Comment: you're welcome happy to hear it worked :) ü